# Seeking good parametrization for the homoclinic solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Could somebody quickly provide me with a good parametrization for the homoclinic 
solution 
$$\frac{p^2}{2}-\frac{q^2}{2}+\frac{q^3}{3}=0$$
of the system
\begin{aligned}
\dot{q}&=p\\
\dot{p}&=q-q^2
\end{aligned}
I am trying to evaluate Melnikov function of the related perturbed system of ODEs. Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Can't you solve for $p=p(q)$ and use $q$ as the parameter?

Comment: I woke up and I had the same idea. Actually it is even better than that. Due to the structure of my perturbation I can eliminate integrals involving $p$ entirely using the relation and just use $q$. You suggested and excellent parametrization!